# Issues with lerna independent versioning + Github Actions

Tags: javascript, github, npm, lerna

this is the first time i am working with lerna and i am having some trouble with the independent versioning, just to start off i ran `lerna init` without `--independent` and i added that in the `lerna.json` later on after i published the initial version.

i am using Github Actions for CI and everything is working ok but lerna keeps on publishing new versions of the package i have even though i don't make changes to it, for example if i add somethings to the README file it will still update the version of the package i have and publish a new version, i am using conventional commits with it as well.

here is my `lerna.json`

```
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "version": "independent",
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "workspaces": true,
  "command": {
    "publish": {
      "conventionalCommits": true,
      "message": "chore: new release"
    }
  }
}
```

i tried deleting all tags and running a build with a change to the package to deploy another version but still every other change that happens outside the package triggers a new release for the package..

Answer (score 1):

Changes to source files will trigger publishing, unless the `ignore-changes` flag is set. It has its own limitations, take a look at this issue with a similar use case: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2437. The conventional-commits will help with the right SemVer tag, but it will at least generate a patch upgrade, for let's say your README.md file updates. It won't prevent a release from being made.

You need to handle it outside of lerna, and invoke `lerna publish` conditionally only when you are sure the changes are relevant. The `lerna changed` command can help you with a preview of what lerna is seeing as a changed package.

Also, lerna will publish child packages when a parent has changed. This can lead to confusions and potential mistakes, remember to take that into account.

Comment: so if i make changes to the root for example, that will trigger a version bump to all packages ? why is that? and is there a way to prevent that ?

Comment: No, the root should not trigger changes, but if you update any package, it will publish all its dependency tree.

Comment: well thats the thing when i update anything in the root, for example my automated build file it triggers a version bump for all the packages which is the issue i am having right now :/

Comment: I cannot say for sure without looking at the complete repo, buti t looks like some configuration issue. Maybe with the `main`/`files` references from the package.json files, or something deeper. NPM may be looking for the root as part of "publishable files", when it is not.

Comment: If possible, please share a sample repository in github replicating this issue, then share here I'll try to take a closer a look.

Comment: this is the repo that has the issue, its a testing repo i made to try out lerna: https://github.com/opllama2/opllamajs